# SQL Update script in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense

I am using Qlik Senes 2.2. The date source from a DB server. I have a table with 6 columns and 2 of them have "null" values (one of the field is a bool type and the other one is text). What I want ,after making selections, to update this two fields in the Data Warehouse from a Qlik Sense app. Is there a possibility to run back the SQL update script from the Qlik Sense.

I hope there is a way that help me out.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Ziad.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "No".

One way to make it work is to develop an extension that posts data (when needed) to web service which then update the database

Comment: Thanks Stefan. It looks like a complex task to do. I mean to update fielda from Qlik sense

Comment: Yes it its. You must realize that QV/QS are tools to explore data not to create data. I know there are cases when there is need to update data back in the database based on selections but this functionality is not available in the core QS. You need to build it by yourself